# Getting Uncaught Error: Type MyModule does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to make a custom module that holds all my UI components. I need it to be compatible with Angular 10 upwards. The package.json of my library looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myLibModule",
  "version": "0.0.15",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Plus my Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { NotificationTrayComponent } from './poettinger-notifications/components/notification-tray/notification-tray.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NotificationComponent } from './poettinger-notifications/components/notification/notification.component';
import { NgbProgressbarModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent, NotificationTrayComponent, NotificationComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgbProgressbarModule
    ],
    exports: [HeaderComponent, NotificationTrayComponent]
})
export class NgxPoettingerComponentsModule { }
```

Now when i try to use it in my Angular application, that has the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "libtest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@it-entwicklung/ngx-poettinger-components": "file:../lib-workspace/dist/myLibModule",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I get the following Error:

```js
Uncaught Error: Type NgxPoettingerComponentsModule does not have 'ɵmod' property.
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1131:1)
    at recurse (core.js:25285:1)
    at recurse (core.js:25296:1)
    at registerNgModuleType (core.js:25281:1)
    at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:25395:1)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:29094:1)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:29344:1)
    at Module.4431 (main.ts:11:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19:1)
    at __webpack_exec__ (log$:23:1)
```

I did compile it without Ivy in production mode. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing something in your imports section in your **NgxPoettingerComponentsModule** module. My guess is you have some component/pipe/service which should be in imports but currently, they are in the declaration section or imports section in your module.

It's better if you can post your module here.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I added the module file to the question